# getting a decimal number while creating section on my texmate?

Tags: latex

```
\documentclass[12pt] {book}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
        \line(1,0){300}\\
        [4mm]
        \huge{\bfseries THIS IS MY NOVEL}\\
        [1mm]
        \line(1,0){300}\\
    \end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\section{Introduction}\label{sec:intro}
```

here I am explaining the story of me and about my family and where I am right now and and so on.

```
\end{document}
```

for the section I am getting an output as 0.1 introduction please let me know how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the document class `book`. The class book defines the commands `\part`, `\chapter`, `\section`, `\subsection`... [see](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Document_Structure#Sectioning_commands).  If you add a section, latex will use `{chapter number}.{section number}` as default. Since you haven't started a chapter, the current chapter number is `0`.

You can either promote your sections to chapters, or change the class from `book` to `article` (or something similar).